# Replacing a line of HTML. I was told to not use RegEx, what do I use?

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm just trying to do a simple deletion of an element in C#. If my  html element contains the text [Store Logo] then I want to remove it. Example:

```
<img src="http://src.sencha.io/300/80/http://images.company.com/[Store Logo]" />
```

Since it has [Store Logo] then I'd like to delete the whole image tag. I was trying to use RegEx to do it but it's hard to understand how to use all the symbols together and I read that I'm not supposed to use regex to parse html. What is the best way to remove it?

Comment: Assuming it's (valid) XML, you can load this into XDocument, then search for the attribute which contains [store logo] and then just remove that element.

Comment: Take a look at using http://nsoup.codeplex.com/

Comment: You sure are not supposed to use [regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2777674)

Comment: @DaveRook it is HTML, I wouldn't assume it is valid XML. Use a HTML parser instead.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, that assumption would generally be bad.  <br> doesn't have an end tag among others

Comment: @Harrison my point exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Here's an example straight from their examples page on how to find all the links in a page:

```
 HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 {
    if(link.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("[Store Logo]"))
       link.ParentNode.RemoveChild(link, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It's a library for parsing HTML that allows to to access the DOM and modify it.